# Add class to section in tpl

Tags: theming

In my template (Bootstrap), in the following line:

```
<section<?php print $content_column_class; ?>>
```

I need to add a custom class AND keep the dynamic column class.
I tried `<section class="myclass <?php print $content_column_class; ?>">` but it give me:

```
<section class=" class=" myclass"="" col-sm-12"="">
```

Any idea what to do?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<?php print $content_column_class; ?>
```

and see what is exactly printed

I think you should try something like this instead

```
<section class="<?php print "myclass ".$content_column_class; ?>">
```

Hope This helps
Cheers

Comment: Thanks, here's what it print: <section class="no-padding class=" col-sm-9""="">. So it prints the class inside the class

Comment: So i guess you might have to fiddle around with $content_column_class. By the way from where do you get the '$content_column_class'?

Answer (score 0):

there is two option to fix this :

1) Add the following code in your .tpl file to add your custom class

`$content_column_class = implode(" myclass", str_split($content_column_class, 16));`

2)
In Bootstrap theme folder go to template > system folder and then open page.vars.php file and and copy

`function bootstrap_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
 if (!empty($variables['page']['sidebar_first']) &&    !empty($variables['page']['sidebar_second'])) {
    $variables['content_column_class'] = ' class="col-sm-6"';
  }
...//Rest of the code
}`

and create a sub theme with template.php and override the above function in template.php :

`function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
if (!empty($variables['page']['sidebar_first']) &&    !empty($variables['page']['sidebar_second'])) {
    $variables['content_column_class'] = ' class="col-sm-6 myclass"';
  }
}`